# Working with dynamic variable names in EL

Tags: jsp, el

In EL, I want to access the value

```
${settings_123456.settingsMap[test].value}
```

The problem is that `settings_123456` is variable. So I stored it in `${setting}` variable and tried `${setting.settingsMap[test].value}` , but it is not working

Edit:

```
Public class Setting {
  Map<String, myClass> settingsMap;
}
Public class myClass {
   private String myTest;
}
```

The model is set with `Setting` object and I need to fetch the value of `myTest` variable in my jsp using jstl. Also note that the key for `settingsMap` is also dynamic that is why you can see `test` variable  in JSP code.

Comment: might help if you post some more code so we can see what you are trying to do

Comment: @reevesy I have updated the question, let me know if you still need some more info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access it by explicitly specifying the scope map.

```
${requestScope[settings_123456].settingsMap[test].value}
```

Use `${sessionScope}` or `${applicationScope}` instead when it's session or application scoped.

Comment: ${requestScope[setting].settingsMap[test].value} worked, where setting variable is set to whatever value is required(e.g. settings_123456 in this case). Thanks :)

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, you kept talking about JSTL while you really meant EL. I have edited your question. Please read the introductory chapter of our JSTL wiki page to learn what JSTL really is: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Answer (score 0):

You have to make `settingsMap` a property, i.e. declare a setter and a getter for it:

```
Public class Setting {
  Map<String, myClass> settingsMap;

  public Map<String, myClass> getSettingsMap() {
    return this.settingsMap;
  }

  public void setSettingsMap(Map<String, myClass> settingsMap) {
    this.settingsMap = settingsMap;
  }   

}
```

Comment: Yes obviously they are there, I just mentioned the properties. All properties have corresponding getters and setters. Infact I can access the map value if I use ${settings_123456.settingsMap[test].value} i.e. if I hard code variable name settings_123456